# Projective dimension of direct summand

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

> I want to prove that if $M$ is an $A$-module with finite projective dimension and $N$ is an $A$-module that is a direct summand of $M$ then the projective dimension of $N$ is less or equal to that of $M$.

I tried using the exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow N \rightarrow M \rightarrow N'\rightarrow 0$$
with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $M=N\oplus N'$ and set $n=\mathrm{pd}(M)$. Let $$0\to X_n\to P_{n-1}\to\cdots\to P_0\to N\to 0$$ be an exact sequence with $P_i$ projective modules, and similarly $$0\to X'_n\to P'_{n-1}\to\cdots\to P'_0\to N'\to 0$$ be an exact sequence with $P'_i$ projective modules. Then take the direct sum of these two sequences and since $\mathrm{pd}(M)=n$ conclude that $X_n\oplus X'_n$ is projective, so both are projective. Now it follows $\mathrm{pd}(N)\le n$.

Comment: I don't understand why the direct sum $X_n\oplus X'_n$ must be projective

Comment: A standard fact in homological algebra says: if the pd of a module is $\le n$ then the $n$th kernel in every projective resolution is projective. (For a proof one can use e.g. the [Generalized Schanuel's lemma](http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/homologicalalgebra.pdf).)

Comment: You can also read the Theorem 7.1.7 from [these notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg7.pdf). (This is why my first suggestion was to use the Ext characterization of projective dimension.)